# Google OAuth2 using the plus.login scope to retrieve circled people

Tags: c#, authentication, google-plus, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm building an MVC 5 app using OAuth2 authentication via the Microsoft.Owin library to authenticate through google (google+). I'm able to add the `email` scope but my attempt to add the `plus.login` scope to request user profile information (ie: people in their circles) doesn't return any extra information in the response (`User` or `Identity`).

According to the [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#login-scopes) adding the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login` scope to the authentication request should provide access to social features like a list of their circled people. But I'm not getting any extra claims returned by adding the `plus.login` scope.

**Startup.Auth.cs**

```
var googleOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions {
    ClientId = "xxx",
    ClientSecret = "xxx",
    Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider {
        OnAuthenticated = async context => {
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Image", context.User.GetValue("image").ToString()));
            // profile doesn't exist in the User object
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Profile", context.User.GetValue("profile").ToString()));
        }
    }
};
googleOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login");
googleOptions.Scope.Add("email");
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOptions);
```

What is the proper way to go about requesting the `plus.login` scope so that I can view the authenticated user's circled people?

Comment: that is the correct scope how do you know its not working?

Comment: I can't find any additional items on the User object within the context or any additional Claims in the Identity object. I feel like I'm just missing something.

Comment: What does the List of visible return? https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list

Comment: sorry, what does "list of visible" refer to?

Comment: Read the documentation people  list visible should return a people list resource of people the current authenticated use has in circles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example lists the people associated with the current authenticated user.

It uses the current [Google-dotnet-Client lib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Plus.v1/1.8.1.1520).

> //PM> Install-Package Google.Apis.Plus.v1

Code ripped directly from the [Git Hub Google-Dotnet-Samples/Google-plus/Diamto-Google-plus-sample](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/master/Google-plus) The tutorial that goes along with it can be found at [Google+ API List with C#](http://www.daimto.com/googleplusapi-list-with-csharp/)

```
#region Person
        /// <summary>
        /// List all of the people in the specified collection
        /// documentation:  https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="service"></param>
        /// <param name="_userId">Get the collection of people for the person identified. Use "me" to indicate the authenticated user.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IList<Person> GetAllPeople(PlusService service, string _userId)
        {
            PeopleResource.ListRequest list = service.People.List(_userId, PeopleResource.ListRequest.CollectionEnum.Visible);
            list.MaxResults = 10;
            PeopleFeed peopleFeed = list.Execute();
            IList<Person> people = new List<Person>(); 

            //// Loop through until we arrive at an empty page
            while (peopleFeed.Items != null)
            {
                // Adding each item  to the list.
                foreach (Person item in peopleFeed.Items)
                {
                    people.Add(item);
                }

                // We will know we are on the last page when the next page token is
                // null.
                // If this is the case, break.
                if (peopleFeed.NextPageToken == null)
                {
                    break;
                }

                // Prepare the next page of results
                list.PageToken = peopleFeed.NextPageToken;

                // Execute and process the next page request
                peopleFeed = list.Execute();

            }

            return people;

        }
```

So assuming your user is authenticated correctly above you should have access to there users in the people list.

> •"visible": The list of people who this user has added to one or more
>   circles, limited to the circles visible to the requesting application.

Comment: I'm confused. I thought that after the user has been authenticated by google, scopes (that describe different endpoints for additional information about the user) are are added to a second request which sends back the requested info? Is that not correct? Am I to make a third request to the people api to get people info?

Comment: You have access you will need to make request to the API if you want the data.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
var googleOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions {
    ClientId = "xxx",
    ClientSecret = "xxx",
    Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider {
        OnAuthenticated = async context => {
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Image", context.User.GetValue("image").ToString()));
            // profile doesn't exist in the User object
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Profile", context.User.GetValue("profile").ToString()));
        }
    }
};
googleOptions.Scope.Add("email+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login");
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOptions);
```